# How do I add an Approver to SharePoint 2010?

Tags: security, sharepoint-2010, workflow

I am still new to SharePoint and am learning so much, but have came in to a few hic-ups and here is one.

I want to add an approver to SharePoint 2010 who has FULL CONTROL. My manager requested that I find out where the approval request are going and redirect them to him. (I have no idea where or how to find this out). Is this possible to do on the Central Administration or must I go into each site/subsite and set him to be the approver this way? Googled and the site was showing me how to approve workflows or how to create approvals, my other resources didn't give much help either. So far I had gone into a few individual sites and set my manager and I up as approvers with full control, but am uncertain if this is the correct procedure or if there is a better way to doi this. For example, have the lower levels inherit from the higher level - set security at the highest level and cascade to the child levels.

Thank You.

Comment: This should be on serverfault.

Comment: Serverfault is another stackexchange site: www.serverfault.com, although I don't agree with it being on serverfault.  Just letting you know what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for one to add an approver to SharePoint 2010, you must be at the top level of the site. Go to Site Actions -> Site Permissions -> Check mark the 'Approvers' check box-> Select Approvers -> Select dropdown for 'New' -> Select 'Add Users' -> Add Their Name to 'Select Users' -> Select 'Ok', then an email will be sent to the user indicating they are now an approver for the specified site.